# Book recommendation - Parallel programming for C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm looking for a book which contains information about the following topics:

- Thread synchronization methods
- Parallel Extension
- Asynchronouse programming (Invoke, BeginInvoke, BackgroundWorker, Threads, ...)

I've already knowledge about these topics but I'll refresh all these in deep and with focus on C#.

The book recommendations should be for C# / .NET 4.0 (not Java) and in English or German.

Thank you guys.
Danny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Parallel Programming wiht .NET](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/) is exactly what you're looking for.

- You can read it [online in the MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx) but it is also available as hardcopy.
- It has a plenty of samples (that can be reused easily) in [C#, VB and F#](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/releases/view/50473).
- To read more about the F# versions, you can read [my blog post series](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-parallel-samples.aspx)

  [image]

Answer (score 3):

Even though it is not specific to parallel programming, [C# in a nutshell 4](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596800963) is a decent reference to understand these concepts

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another nice document comes from Microsoft:

- [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en)

Comment: Stephen Toub authored this and was also a co-author on the book above. Not surprisingly they share a lot of the same content. The book expands on the white paper considerably.

Answer (score 1):

C# 4.0 in a nutshell by o reilly publications

[http://www.amazon.com/C-4-0-Nutshell-Definitive-Reference/dp/0596800959/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1298027628&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596800959)